# How to make navbar full width?

Tags: html, css

I want to make navbar full width of the screen but for some reason, it's full width only on the right side.

Left side of the navbar is not full width. Can someone please tell me how can I do it?

[image]

CSS code looks like that:

```
.head{
    background-color:rgb(48, 87, 56);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 3px rgb(155, 153, 153);
    margin-top: -2%;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left), try to add

```
left: 0;
```

in your `css` file to close the gap on the left side.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, I should see your code, but try it :
reset your body

```
 *{
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
 }
```

Comment: I added CSS code, can you check now please?

Comment: @Chrisss There is also need to add your html.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help:

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 6px 8px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  align-items:center;
  background-color:rgb(48, 87, 56);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 3px rgb(155, 153, 153);
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
}

.logo {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <img alt="" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png/google-logo-png-suite-everything-you-need-know-about-google-newest-0.png" class="logo" />
</div>
```